# Dropdown select datas from laravel using vue js 1

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have this issue below, I can get datas from DB and read them in a console, but I don't get where is error when I try to get on dropdown select. Here is the code

```
     loadProducts: function(data){
    this.$http.get('/pro_id')
    .then(function(response){
         this.form.list = response.data
        console.log(this.form.list)
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}db
```

in my console i have

```
[{"id":15,"pro_name":"Ch\u00e1 de Cavalinha"},{"id":14,"pro_name":"Agrimonia Eupatoria"},{"id":13,"pro_name":"Ch\u00e1 de Mulungu - Erythrina velutina"},{"id":12,"pro_name":"hidroxido de Aluminio"},{"id":11,"pro_name":"Amox"},{"id":10,"pro_name":"azitrimizina"},{"id":9,"pro_name":"camomila"},{"id":8,"pro_name":"Paracetamol"},{"id":7,"pro_name":"Colgate"},{"id":6,"pro_name":"mebendazol"},{"id":5,"pro_name":"fluegen"},{"id":4,"pro_name":"coldaFlu"},{"id":3,"pro_name":"Amoxicilina md5"},{"id":2,"pro_name":"para rapidos"},{"id":1,"pro_name":"Paracetamol"}]
```

but when I try to read them in my view, it brings empty fields

```
<select name="pro_stock_id" v-model="product.pro_stock_id" class="form-control select" v-if="form.list"  >

                    <option v-for="listar in form.list" :value="listar.id">@{{ listar.pro_name}}</option>
               </select>
```

I am not using components, since i started this project with predifined template from laravel plugin adminLte

Comment: Please install Vue Devtools extension on Chrome and check if the `form` value is getting updated. The code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does your product.pro_stock_id in **select v-model=product.pro_stock_id** have the same id that you got from your result, if its different you will not get select value as it does not match the options.